# Boost allocators performance

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, allocator

I am trying to increase the performance by using boost::container::allocators.

Created [a simple experiment](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3lJlCKGNtZupVtBG):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/container/pmr/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/container/pmr/set.hpp>
#include <boost/container/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/container/node_allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/container/adaptive_pool.hpp>

template<typename Vector>
void pushBackTest(bool makeReserve)
{
    Vector v;

    const std::size_t count = 10000000;
    if (makeReserve)
    {
        v.reserve(count);
    }
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(typename Vector::value_type{});
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    const std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end - start;
    std::cout << duration.count() << std::endl;
}

template<typename Set>
void setInsertTest()
{
    Set v;

    const std::size_t count = 1000000;

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
    {
        v.insert(std::rand());
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    const std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end - start;
    std::cout << duration.count() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::srand((unsigned)std::time(nullptr));

    std::cout << "Vector" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "No reserve" << std::endl;
    pushBackTest<std::vector<int>>(false);
    pushBackTest<std::vector<int, boost::container::allocator<int>>>(false);
    pushBackTest<boost::container::vector<int, boost::container::allocator<int>>>(false);
    pushBackTest<boost::container::vector<int, boost::container::allocator<int>>>(false);
    pushBackTest<boost::container::pmr::vector<int>>(false);

    std::cout << "Reserve" << std::endl;
    pushBackTest<std::vector<int>>(true);
    pushBackTest<std::vector<int, boost::container::allocator<int>>>(true);
    pushBackTest<boost::container::vector<int, boost::container::allocator<int>>>(true);
    pushBackTest<boost::container::vector<int, boost::container::allocator<int>>>(true);
    pushBackTest<boost::container::pmr::vector<int>>(true);

    std::cout << "Set" << std::endl;
    setInsertTest<std::set<int>>();
    setInsertTest<std::set<int, std::less<int>, boost::container::node_allocator<int>>>();
    setInsertTest<std::set<int, std::less<int>, boost::container::adaptive_pool<int>>>();
    setInsertTest<boost::container::set<int>>();
    setInsertTest<boost::container::set<int, std::less<int>, boost::container::node_allocator<int>>>();
    setInsertTest<boost::container::set<int, std::less<int>, boost::container::adaptive_pool<int>>>();
    setInsertTest<boost::container::pmr::set<int>>();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `clang++12 prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -march=native -I/opt/wandbox/boost-1.73.0/clang-head/include -std=c++14`

Results:

```
Vector
No reserve
0.10387
0.095851
0.104992
0.0982694
0.102469
Reserve
0.0372922
0.0489831
0.0518053
0.052593
0.0680981
Set
0.760118
0.7739
0.769929
1.09121
0.685224
0.747359
1.18725
```

As far as I can see, allocators do not give any performance boost.
Could anyone please take a look and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you need to create and post a [MRE]. Questions should be self-contained. Also you need to show your results as well as the compiler flags used to compile and the measuring methodology.

Comment: When you do any performance measurements [do not forget enable optimizations](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uWoxq4pCgboeVeAs) `-O3` (gain is x6-10 faster).

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I can see, allocators do not give any performance boost.

In your particular benchmark, calling `vector<>::reserve` before doing `vector<>::push_back` yields the biggest performance improvement regardless of what allocator you use.

When you don't call `vector<>::reserve`, the benchmark allocates ever larger blocks of memory when the vector grows, and this scenario is not what allocators are optimized for. Modern allocators are often optimized for minimal lock contention when used from different threads, less memory fragmentation, better cache utilization, none of which your benchmark can benefit from / observe and measure.

---

In `setInsertTest` it inserts the result of `std::rand` call. This pseudo-random number generator must be reset with a call `std::srand(0)`, so that each benchmark uses the very same sequence of pseudo-random numbers, otherwise it measures performance of different containers on disjoint samples from the same distribution.

---

You may like to use [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) because it automates

- timing,
- reporting,
- disables benchmark code elision,
- can report statistical measures of central tendency (mean and median) and dispersion (standard deviation)

without you having to write a line of code for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! UPD: I have update the example by removing vector tests. You've mentioned that modern allocators decrease memory fragmentation and work better with the cache. I have created iterationTest that measures iteration time over sets. I've expected better performance with allocators because of more cache hits. But the overall results iare the same. Allocators give no performance boost at this sample. PS: GoogleBenchmark is a great thing, but I do not need accuracy now, I am just investigating the overall picture.